# dynamically change options in dropdown list in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i tried to create dynamically changing dropdown list in angularJS

angulars.js

```
 var option1Options = ["Class","Category","Option","Question","Group"];
 var option2Options = [["Group","ProductModel"],
                      ["Class","ProductModel"],
                      ["Class","Group","ProductModel"],
                      ["Group","ProductModel"],
                      ["ProductModel"]];
 $scope.myCtrl= function()
 {
    $scope.options1 = option1Options;
    $scope.options2 = []; 
    $scope.getOptions2 = function(){
        var key = $scope.options1.indexOf($scope.child);
        $scope.options2 =  option2Options[2];
    };
  }
```

page.html

```
 <div   id="CreateChild"  ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <select ng-model="child" ng-options="option for option in options1"  ng-change="getOptions2()">
 </select>
 <select ng-model="parent" ng-options="option for option in options2">
 </select>
 </div>
```

in angulars.js i was unable to get the index of first dropdown list array. the value of **key** is assigned as -1 and the option2 is assigned as undefined.
can any one help me with this

Comment: There are some typos errors on your code... Could you to create a plunkr or jsbin with your code? (example... you define option20Options with array of array, and on function, you try to get option20options[2] with doesn't exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small workaround for this requirement, though it is not a straight answer, I believe this would help you...

Add this to your controller...

```
$scope.getOptions1Idx = function(){
   var mySelectedOption = $scope.child;
   var i = 0;
   for(i=0;i< option1Options.length;i++){
        if(option1Options[i]==mySelectedOption){
          break;
        }
   }
   return i;
}
```

and change your getOptions2 function as follows

```
$scope.getOptions2 = function(){
        $scope.options2 =  option2Options[getOptions1Idx()];
    };
```

This can be done in much better fashion by avoiding for loop provided if you choose to change your array structure with predefined index some thing like var `option1Options = [{id:0,option:"Class"},{id:1,option:"Category"},{id:2,option:"Option"},{id:3,option:"Question","Group"}];`

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem with this. In terms of styling I found my way around it by creating a list instead of a select option

```
<div class='btn-group'>
   <button class='form-control col-md-3' data-toggle='dropdown'>
      {{value}} <span class='caret'></span>
   </button>
   <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li ng-repeat='type in callType' class='col-md-3'>
        <a href='#' ng-click='select(type)'>{{type.name}}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Then the controller is used to take in the objects, call a method to change each object and then set a default for the drop down list. You can see it at the link below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nwXmMif8vjj92pQmalb2